# Multiple assignments inside if-statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variable-assignment

Why can't I do this:

```
var fooElement, barElements;
if(fooElement = document.getElementById('foo') && barElements = fooElement.getElementsByTagName('bar') && barElements[0] && barElements[0].onclick)
{
    console.log(barElements[0].onclick);
}
```

This won't work either:

```
var foo, bar;
if(foo = true && bar = true)
{
    console.log('yay');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this (it should give you a clue):

```
var foo, bar;
if((foo = true) && (bar = true))
{
    console.log('yay');
}
```

Comment: The precedence by default are to put the assignment last, so that all of the && statements are calculated first. This is easy to see when you mistakenly use = rather than ==, and makes sense if you consider the more common use of the combinations of = and &&.

Answer (score 2):

Check Operator Precedence,Use

```
if((foo = true) && (bar = true))
{
    alert(foo);
}
```

UPD: Don't forget that following code will not set `bar` to true because && is `Short Circuit` operator

```
if((foo = false) && (bar = true))
{
    alert(foo);
}
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq7L4/)